# Replace core data model without migration

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios4

I have changed my core data model quite extensively. There are loads of question how to migrate the old data into the new model, however i don't need to migrate anything.

I just would like to replace the current Core Data instance. How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using a persistant store coordinator with `NSSQLiteStoreType`.  Just change the name of the url for your persistant store coordinator.  If the previous version used a url called `MyApp.sqlite`, change it to `MyAppVersionX.sqlite`.

Comment: Yep. Correct, thats what I did. Thanks!