# How do I overcome XCode object model version error?

Tags: xcode, core-data, versioning, object-model

I'm currently running OS X 10.7.4 and using XCode 4.3.2.  I'm coming back to XCode from not really using it in production since version 2.x.  That said, I have a test Core Data application (MacOS not iPhone) I'm getting familiar with.  There is 0 code -- all Interface Builder at the moment.  I changed the data model a couple days ago, and have been getting the following error since:

```
The managed object model version used to open the persistent store is incompatible with the one that was used to create the persistent store
```

I have encountered several related threads, including, but not limited to:

[Replace core data model without migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103045/replace-core-data-model-without-migration)

[Incompatible Object Model Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790933/incompatible-object-model-version)

[Wipe all data stored with CoreData when the model has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778430/wipe-all-data-stored-with-coredata-when-the-model-has-changed)

However, none have resolved my problem.  Again, I am using no code.  Also, despite other pages and forum posts I have encountered:

http://www.matthew-long.com/2007/11/02/the-managed-object-model-version-used-to-open-the-persistent-store-is-incompatible-with-the-one-that-was-used-to-create-the-persistent-store/

…there is no xml file in ~/Library/Application Support/AppName for me to delete.  There's actually no folder anywhere in Library with my "AppName".  I'm sure the answer is fairly trivial, but I have been beating my head against a wall trying to figure it out.

I'm currently reading the Apple documentation on versioning, etc (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html), but I'm hoping someone will post an answer before my eyes glaze over.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you find the code for creating your persistent store?

Comment: try also to do a clean for your project. hope it helps.

Comment: No, as I mentioned, there is no code to "find".  Also, I have cleaned it, multiple times, and still nothing.  When I Google for the error it seems to be sufficiently common, but no solution yet seems to fix it.  *shrug*

Comment: You should look for `- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator` method in `YourAppDelegate.m` file. Check again.

Comment: Yes, I actually did that.  I misunderstood your initial post.  I simply set the *options* and passed them to the PSC before returning it.  Feel free to actually answer the question and I will give you the points (as opposed to me answering it myself).  Thanks again!